# Create Index with Dynamic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, indices, dynamic-mapping

I'm trying to create an index with dynamic mapping. It seems like there are some error in the mapping template. The dataset contains string, numeric value and dates. I've to accommodate all those.

```
mapping = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 2,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": { 
            "properties": {  
                "details": {
                    "dynamic_templates": [
                       {
                         "name_template": {
                           "match": "*",
                           "mapping": {
                             "type": "string",
                             "dynamic": True
                           }
                         }
                       }
                     ]
    
        }
    }
```

this is the code I'm using to create new index

```
if es.indices.exists(index="es_index") == False:
   index_creation = es.indices.create(index="es_index", ignore=400, body=mapping)
   print("index created: ",index_creation)
```

I'm getting the error

```
 index created:  {'error': {'root_cause': 
[{'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Root mapping definition has 
unsupported parameters:  [details : {dynamic_templates=[{name_template=
{mapping={dynamic=true, type=string}, match=*}}]}]'}], 'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: 
Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [details : {dynamic_templates=[{name_template={mapping={dynamic=true, type=string}, match=*}}]}]', 'caused_by': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [details : {dynamic_templates=[{name_template={mapping={dynamic=true, type=string}, match=*}}]}]'}}, 'status': 400}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) correctly, here is how it should look like. `dynamic_templates` should be in its own array as a sibling of properties. Also you don't need to specify `_doc`:

```
mapping = {
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "name_template": {
          "path_match": "details.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "details": {
          "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I got another error. index created:  {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'No type specified for field [details]'}], 'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No type specified for field [details]', 'caused_by': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'No type specified for field [details]'}}, 'status': 400}. What is the type to be added for the details field?

Comment: Actually, there were other errors, I've updated my answer completely. Please have a look